# LINQ Checking all Records in Group

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am querying linqQuery from linqQuery2 because LINQ to CRM doesn't support GroupBy. The code below works, but it only checks against the first record found. Is there something like First() but checks all the records and not just the First one?

```
var linqQuery = (from r in orgServiceContext.CreateQuery("opportunity")
select new
    {
        OpportunityId = !r.Contains("opportunityid") ? string.Empty : r["opportunityid"],
        CustomerId = !r.Contains("customerid") ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)r["customerid"]).Name,
        OwnerId = !r.Contains("ownerid") ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)r["ownerid"]).Id.ToString(),
        OwnerName = !r.Contains("ownerid") ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)r["ownerid"]).Name.ToString(),
        EmailedToRSM = !r.Contains("new_emailedtorsm") ? false : ((Boolean)r["new_emailedtorsm"]),
        LeadStatus = !r.Contains("new_leadstatus") ? "100000000" : ((OptionSetValue)r["new_leadstatus"]).Value.ToString(),
    });

var linqQuery2 = (from f in linqQuery.ToList()
group f by f.OwnerId into myGroup
    select new
        {
            OwnerName = myGroup.First().OwnerName,
            OwnerId = myGroup.First().OwnerId,
            LeadStatus = myGroup.First().LeadStatus.ToString(),
            EmailedToRSM = myGroup.First().EmailedToRSM,
            OrderCount = myGroup.Count()
        });

foreach (var c in linqQuery2)
{

        if (c.LeadStatus.ToString() == "100000000")
            {

            //Count records that have a Lead Status of 100000000

            }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to see the wood for the trees here, because of poor formatting and a vast number of properties involved. Can you express the same problem with a simpler example?

Comment: Sorry Jon, reformatted and shortened. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you're using `First()` to start with. How about:

```
var grouped = linqQuery.GroupBy(f => f.OwnerId).ToList();
```

Now each entry in "grouped" is a grouping. You can now use:

```
foreach (var group in grouped)
{
    Console.WriteLine("OwnerId: {0}", group.Key);
    int leadCount = group.Count(c => c.LeadStatus == 100000000);
    // etc - do what whatever else you want with the group

    // Let's dump all the customer IDs...
    foreach (var entry in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(entry.CustomerID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How do a go about getting the other variables from linqQuery. So in the foreach I would also want to display CustomerId, EmailedToRSM, Owner, etc. That possible? Thanks!

Comment: @Justin: In exactly the same way. Within each group, there are all the items which have the same owner ID. (I've added an example dumping all the customer IDs to my answer.)

Comment: Awesome! In the foreach loop I want to end out an email for each group in the count. I'm doing that now but it sends out an email for each record. Any way to make so it only sends out one email per group? Thanks!

Comment: @Justin: It sounds like you're sending the mail in the *inner* foreach loop; you should do it in the *outside* loop if you want one mail per group.

Comment: Last question sorry! New to LINQ and CRM. How would I add a Where clause to this "var grouped = linqQuery.GroupBy(f => f.OwnerId).ToList();"

Comment: @Justin: Well what are you trying to filter?

Comment: I'm looking to only filter by records with a LeadStatus of 100000000 and EmailedToRSM of true. Thanks!

Comment: @Justin: Then put that before the grouping: `var grouped = linqQuery.Where(c => c.LeadStatus == 100000000 && c.EmailedToRSM).GroupBy(...);`

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to use all the items in `myGroup`. By calling `First()` you're limiting yourself to the first item only.

You could write your query as follows:

```
var query = from f in linqQuery.ToList()
            group f by f.OwnerId into myGroup
            from item in myGroup
            select new
            {
                OwnerName = item.OwnerName,
                OwnerId = item.OwnerId,
                LeadStatus = item.LeadStatus.ToString(),
                EmailedToRSM = item.EmailedToRSM,
                OrderCount = myGroup.Count()
            };
```

However, note that by doing so you would be flattening the results.